# edit-and-execute-command bash with sublime text

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, sublimetext3

In a bash terminal session, I notice that the **edit-and-execute-command** <kbd>C-xC-e</kbd> does not work with Sublime Text 3.

I've set `EDITOR=subl`, but when I try to edit a command line from bash, sublime-text opens an empty window.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: I have reproduced the behaviour you described. (Nano works as command editor though) Looks like it could be a bug. If it is a bug the trick now is to know who to report it to. Where did you learn about the C-x C-e short cut? I checked the bash man page and the readline man page can't find a reference to it.

Comment: It's on man bash (at least on OS X): edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
              Invoke  an editor on the current command line, and execute the result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke $FCEDIT, $EDI-
              TOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

Comment: Get here : http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Miscellaneous-Commands.html

Comment: Can you try to use EDITOR="subl -w" (should be implied from stdin but pheraps something is not working correctly)

Comment: @terencehill -w is the answer. I was searching for "C-x C-e" instead of "C-xC-e" Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should export the EDITOR as:

```
EDITOR="subl -w"
```

as:

> To use Sublime Text as the editor for many commands that prompt for
>   input, set your EDITOR environment variable:
>
> `export EDITOR='subl -w'`
>
> Specifying -w will cause the subl command to not exit until the file is >closed.

Full explanation [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html)